# How to add 3 new rows equal to the previous row in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server

Was wondering if theres some sort of previous value function i could use. Im trying expand an "hour" column so it can correspond to a "MinuteOfDay" Column. so it would look like

[image: [Table]]

And so on. I am very new to SQL

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: 2014 management studio

Comment: This might be of interest: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained--part-1/

Comment: First, I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Do you have a list of minutes and you are trying to find the hour? Divide by 60 and round.

Comment: Basically trying to have the MinuteOfDay Column list all the minutes by 15, and the Hour Column list all the hours of the day. Right now all i have is an existing Hour column that wont correspond to the minutes column because instead of having 4 rows it only has one. I am sorry english is not my first language so if its hard to understand im sorry

Comment: Are you just trying to create the data for this table? I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I think this recursive cte does exactly what you want:

```
 with cte 
 as 
 (select 2400 as HH, 0 as MM
 UNION ALL
 select (HH + 25) as HH, MM + 15 as MM from cte where MM < 1500)
 select CASE WHEN (HH/100) % 25  = 24 THEN 24
        ELSE (HH/100) % 25 + 1 
        END as HH, MM from cte where MM <= 1425;
```

No need to create any table or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a shot in the dark at your requirements. I assume that you really want the hour to be 0 at midnight as 24:00 is NOT a valid time.

I am using a tally table for this solution. They are so helpful for so many things that I keep a view on my system like this.

create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

```
WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

This allows me to reuse this whenever I need to. We an leverage this tally table quite effectively for this type of thing.

```
SELECT MyHour = H.N - 1
    , MyMinutes = ((H.N - 1) * 60) + (M.N - 1) * 15
FROM dbo.cteTally H
CROSS JOIN dbo.cteTally M
where H.N <= 24
    AND M.N <= 4
```